# Apache monitoring tool that reads and organize Apache Logs

Tags: server, apache2, monitor, log

I got tired looking for a GUI tool that just read and organize Apache log files. Reading several redundant lines of the log file is a hill. I searched here and Google for a free GUI tool that performs this task but I could not find anything else SeaLion but its website has some warning hazard from FF.
Any one could recommend a tool that do that even cli?

Comment: Would [GoAccess](https://goaccess.io/) work for you? I've used it with NGINX, and it wors well

Comment: @cocomac Thank you very much, it looks promising for my need.